# How to make a function for counting no of stops

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, functional-programming

I wanted to split the text and and count the no of stop btw the arrival and departure destination .
route column is given below. Need to make a new column name as 'No of stop' where stops value is count.

```
Route
BLR → DEL
CCU → IXR → BBI → BLR   
DEL → LKO → BOM → COK
CCU → NAG → BLR
BLR → NAG → DEL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can count the `sep`

```
df.Route.str.count('→')-1
0    0
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    1
Name: Route, dtype: int64
```